# MRAID test creative

Tags: ads, mraid

I'm looking for test `MRAID` creative which executes all `MRAID` functionality, something like this:

https://github.com/nexage/sourcekit-mraid-ios/tree/master/demo/creatives

But in one `HTML` source file.
F.e I need plenty of buttons which executes different `MRAID` commands.

I'm not interested in `mraid.js` itself.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[MRAID Sample Ads](https://wiki.operamediaworks.com/display/AMS/MRAID+Sample+Ads) is a good place to start, however this doesn't meet your 'all MRAID functionality' in one ad requirement.